# Consuming data from WikiNews

Tags: c#

I have been scouring the net but I can't seem to find any examples of consuming data from [WikiNews](http://en.wikinews.org/wiki/Main_Page).  They have an RSS feed with links to individual stories as HTML, but I would like to get the data in a structured format such as XML etc.

By structured format I mean an XML file for each story that has a defined XML schema (XSD) file. See: [http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_intro.asp][2]

Has anyone written a program that consumes stories from WikiNews? Do they have a documented API?

I would like to use C# to collect selected stories and store them in SQL Server 2008.

[2]: By "structured format" I mean something like an XML schema (XSD) file. See: http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_intro.asp

Comment: What do you mean by "structured format?" The RSS feed will give you title, date, and body in XML. 

I'm not up on C# and SQL Server, but this is about 10 lines of code with python.

Comment: You're not being very specific.  Their RSS feed returns XML, and you want XML.  What is it that is missing?  You tell me that you want the story itself in XML.  The story doesn't make sense in XML.  The story is text.  What elements would there be if it were XML?

Comment: Gabriel, I guess I am not being clear. I don't want to "screen scrape" an article and try to decipher what is what, I want to get it in a data friendly format such as an XML file with an associated XSD (which WikiNews pages lack). The problem is that a story is not "just text". I am shure that in WikiNews's backing store it has specific fields for the rows on the history tab (time of last edit, user making the edit etc. If you look at the page source you will see that these are rendered together as <li> and tell nothing about their structure.

Comment: Then consider what you're really asking.  You want their data in a format that it has not been given.  You really only have 2 options.  Ask them to provide it in the way you need, or convert it yourself.

Comment: "You want their data in a format that it has not been given." I don't know that. That is the purpose of this question, to see if anyone has found an interface to WikiNews in a computer friendly format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The software they use [has an API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API) but I'm not sure if WikiNews supports it.

Answer (score 0):

Their feed:  http://feeds.feedburner.com/WikinewsLatestNews

If you put that in your browser and read the source, you'll see that it is XML.  The XML contains the title, description, a link, etc.  Only the description is in HTML.

Here is the beginning of the response:

```
<rss xmlns:creativeCommons="http://backend.userland.com/creativeCommonsRssModule" xmlns:feedburner="http://rssnamespace.org/feedburner/ext/1.0" version="2.0"> 
         <channel> 
             <title>Wikinews</title> 
             <description>Wikinews RSS feed</description> 
             <language>en</language> 
             <link>http://en.wikinews.org</link> 
             <copyright>Creative Commons Attribution 2.5 (unless otherwise noted)</copyright> 
             <generator>Wikinews Fetch</generator> 
             <ttl>180</ttl> 
             <docs>http://none</docs> 
                 <atom10:link xmlns:atom10="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/WikinewsLatestNews" /><feedburner:info uri="wikinewslatestnews" /><atom10:link xmlns:atom10="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" rel="hub" href="http://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com/" /><creativeCommons:license>http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.5/</creativeCommons:license><feedburner:browserFriendly>This is an XML content feed. It is intended to be viewed in a newsreader or syndicated to another site.</feedburner:browserFriendly><item> 
                     <title>Lufthansa pilots begin strike</title> 
                     <link>http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/WikinewsLatestNews/~3/1K2xloPGlmI/Lufthansa_pilots_begin_strike</link> 
                     <description>&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href="http://en.wikinews.org/w/index.php?title=File:LocationGermany.png&amp;filetimestamp=20060604120306" class="image" title="A map showing the location of Germany"&gt;&lt;img alt="A map showing the location of Germany" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/de/LocationGermany.png/196px-LocationGermany.png" width="196" height="90" /&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;b class="published"&gt;&lt;span id="publishDate" class="value-title" title="2010-02-22"&gt;&lt;/span&gt;Monday, February 22, 2010&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;The pilot's union of &lt;a href="http://en.wikinews.org/wiki/Germany" title="Germany" class="mw-redirect"&gt;German&lt;/a&gt; airline &lt;a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lufthansa" class="extiw" title="w:Lufthansa"&gt;Lufthansa&lt;/a&gt; have begun a four-day strike over pay and job security. Operations at subsidiary airlines &lt;a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lufthansa_Cargo" class="extiw" title="w:Lufthansa Cargo"&gt;Lufthansa Cargo&lt;/a&gt; and &lt;a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germanwings" class="extiw" title="w:Germanwings"&gt;Germanwings&lt;/a&gt; are also affected by the strike.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;em&gt;&lt;a href='http://en.wikinews.org/wiki/Lufthansa_pilots_begin_strike'&gt;More...&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/em&gt;&lt;div class="feedflare"&gt;
&lt;a href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/WikinewsLatestNews?a=1K2xloPGlmI:9SJI0YV04-M:yIl2AUoC8zA"&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/WikinewsLatestNews?d=yIl2AUoC8zA" border="0"&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/WikinewsLatestNews?a=1K2xloPGlmI:9SJI0YV04-M:7Q72WNTAKBA"&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/WikinewsLatestNews?d=7Q72WNTAKBA" border="0"&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/WikinewsLatestNews?a=1K2xloPGlmI:9SJI0YV04-M:YwkR-u9nhCs"&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/WikinewsLatestNews?d=YwkR-u9nhCs" border="0"&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;/a&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;</description> 
<guid isPermaLink="false">http://en.wikinews.org/wiki/Lufthansa_pilots_begin_strike</guid> 

<feedburner:origLink>http://en.wikinews.org/wiki/Lufthansa_pilots_begin_strike</feedburner:origLink></item>
```

Comment: That gets the RSS feed from feedburner, but does not get a story as XML from WikiNews.

Comment: I think you're going to have to be more specific. If you were to get the story in XML, what elements would you have?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really unclear! but I guess you want to **format** the feeds of WikiNews, to be readable in a more friendly way (as if you are reading it in WikiNews itself), am I correct?

If so, then you have to know that [RSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rss) are XML with a standard format, and not related to WikiNews, and you can transform **any** RSS feeds to be displayed in -say- HTML with [XSLT](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/default.asp).

If you need to get the story itself, you can use the given link in the feed, and display it in a webbrowser control (if you are developing a windows application).

Do you need something else other than what I have said?

Comment: What you have basically said is that one can grab the story in a web browser control and then do "screen scraping". I know one can do screen scraping on _any_ website. that is not the same as getting the data used to generate the page in a standard format like XML with a XSD. In other words there is a big difference between a html file and xml with xsd.

Consider Stack Overflow, would you rather screen the site to get data or use the monthly data dump?

Comment: @Jonny: As I've said before, if you want the data in another format, you have 2 choices.  Either ask WikiNews to provide it in the desired format or convert it yourself.  No one has done it yet, so you're going to have to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Current wikiextractor has some bugs with some unrecognized templates, that I solve with two `sed` commands, this way:

- Download the Wikinews dumps from https://dumps.wikimedia.org/backup-index.html
  Files: language_code: xx  xxwikinew
- Use WikiExtractor to extract text from the wiki pages
  (See old stats and language code at: https://stats.wikimedia.org/wikinews/EN/Sitemap.htm )
- Get the sofwtare: https://github.com/attardi/wikiextractor

```
    pip install wikiextractor
    sed -e 's/{{w|[^|}]*|\([^|}]*\)}}/\1/g' enwikinews-20230920-pages-meta-current.xml  | sed -e 's/\[\[[^]|]*|\([^]|]*\)\]\]/\1/g' > enwikinews-20230920-pages-meta-current_parsed.xml
    wikiextractor -b 100M -o en enwikinews-20230920-pages-meta-current_parsed.xml
```

(You can add  `--json` to get a json file instead; there are other options, e.g. for links).